# Source for Shuttle SRB segment history diagrams

Tags: space-shuttle, history, srb

I'm looking for a source for these ATK booster segment history images.

Sadly absent user TildalWave posted a comment with a [link](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-051010a.html) to an article containing this one 3 1/2 years ago.

[image]

I've finally obtained the long-sought Giant Data Dump of shuttle booster segment usage and I'm writing python scripts to convert it into useful form.  These charts are super helpful for checking my work.

So far I've found images for STS-132 (thanks to TildalWave's comment), STS-134, STS-135,  Aries 1-X, and SLS QM-1.

If anyone has a source for these charts so I could pull a few more down as test cases, I'd appreciate knowing about it.

Edit: I would happily take individual charts if there is no general source.

Comment: Since the Shuttle is no more, ATK is no more, Orbital/ATK is no more, I suspect you might have trouble finding the source for this.

Comment: One might reasonably suspect that's why I asked for help.

Comment: I gave an upvote, and almost wrote "good luck", but I realized that that might have been misconstrued. The attribution in the linked article is collectSPACE/ATK, and the article references an email from ATK to collectSPACE. The data might well have been in that email.

Comment: Your comment was useful, I added the history tag and edited the question. Thanks for helping me clarify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have managed to scrounge up (around the internet) SRB Case Use Histories for the following flights and tests:

- STS-092
- STS-093
- STS-096
- STS-097
- STS-098
- STS-099
- STS-100
- STS-102
- STS-103
- STS-105
- STS-107
- STS-108
- STS-109
- STS-111
- STS-113
- STS-132
- STS-133
- STS-134
- STS-135
- Ares 1-X
- SLS QM-1

For a goodly part of last year I was communicating with the collator of the SRB segment use data mentioned in this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31883/6944) to work out discrepancies between these diagrams and his data. Most of the discrepancies that I identified in that data dump have been corrected, although there are still a few. Some (most) of these discrepancies are likely errors on the Case Use Histories.